# What are the differences between rbenv, rvm, and chruby?

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv, chruby

I'm new-ish to Ruby and Rails.  I am looking for a purely objective list of features and advantages/disadvantages of each.  In an effort to keep preference out of this, please refrain from answering unless you have used all 3 systems.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There's three main options available today:

- [rvm](http://rvm.io) which is the most established, but also the most intrusive in terms of shell modifications.
- [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) which is lower impact, and still works as well.
- [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) which purports to be even lighter than `rbenv`.

Personally I prefer `rbenv` because it works well with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and doesn't mangle the shell environment as much, but tend to use `rvm` on servers where that doesn't matter because they're set up for a very specific purpose.

Comment: fwiw, rbenv is the tool recommended on http://rubyonrails.org/download/ as of today.

Comment: @benjamin I'm a big fan of `rbenv` myself, but I've found `rvm` works better on servers where you need a system-wide install, or at least it meshes better with Ansible.